# Which characters are named after birds?

Tags: one-piece

I know that Oda named a few of his female characters, like Tsuru, Tashigi and Kuina, after different kinds of birds, but I'm only aware of these three characters following that theme. Out of curiosity, are there more female characters who share their names with birds?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Female characters who share their names with birds (**bolded** is the bird name):

- [Nico **Robin**](https://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Robin): [Japanese robin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_robin)
- [**Nojiko**](https://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Nojiko): [Japanese yellow bunting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yellow_bunting)
- [**Tashigi**](https://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Tashigi): [Common snipe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_snipe)
- [**Kuina**](https://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Kuina): [Water rail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water_rail)
- [**Aisa**](https://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Aisa): [Seaducks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mergini)
- [O-**Tsuru**-san](https://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Tsuru): [Crane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crane_(bird))
- [**Hina**](https://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Hina): [Chick (young chicken)](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/chick)
- [**Mozu**](https://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Mozu): [Bull-headed shrike](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bull-headed_shrike)
- [**Kiwi**](https://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Kiwi): [Kiwi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kiwi)

For the sake of completeness, for the male characters:

- [Donquixote Do**flamingo**](https://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Donquixote_Doflamingo): [Flamingo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flamingo)
- [Dracule Mi**hawk**](https://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Mihawk): [Hawk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawk)
- [Kuzan/**Aokiji**](https://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Aokiji): [Japanese green pheasent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_pheasant)
- [**Fukuro**](https://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Fukurou): [Owl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Owl)
- [**Karasu**](https://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Karasu): [Crow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crow)
- [Pell the **Falcon**](https://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Pell): [Falcon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falcon)
- [Marco the **Phoenix**](https://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Marco): [Phoenix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phoenix_(mythology))

**Note**: this list only includes character names. It excludes characters/others that are directly related to birds (e.g. [Monet](https://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Monet)'s harpy).

---

Sources:

- fpbird's ameblo (Japanese): [1](https://ameblo.jp/fpbird/entry-11368648938.html), [2](https://ameblo.jp/fpbird/entry-11701491137.html), [3](https://ameblo.jp/fpbird/entry-12093840661.html)
- Naver Matome (Japanese): [1](https://matome.naver.jp/odai/2150719047298727501)

Comment: Note: there's always a chance I missed some people. Just let me know in the comment.

Answer (score 5):

[Robin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_robin) might be the most obvious one.
It's also worth to mention that her autograph is a bird as well:

[image: Nico Robins autograph]